# Use less than or equal in odata msgraph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently working on calendar events and I'd like to get events only between two included dates. 
I would like to use the comparison operator 'le' in the msgraph api, but it does not work correctly. It seems it is working like a 'lt'. I have no problem with 'ge'.

Here is my json events start/end date:

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-06-13T12:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
},
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-06-13T15:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
}
```

Here is my query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/events?$filter=(start/dateTime ge '2017-06-13' and end/dateTime le '2017-06-13')
```

This query returns nothing! I tried with only start or end date but it's the same result.

Can anyone tell me what’s wrong with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters, "start/dateTime" and "end/dateTime" are essentially dateTime values [of a single point of time](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/datetimetimezone).

So when you perform the comparison "(start/dateTime ge '2017-06-13' and end/dateTime le '2017-06-13')'against the date "2017-06-13", it actually compares it as "(start/dateTime ge '2017-06-13T00:00:00.0000000' and end/dateTime le '2017-06-13T00:00:00.0000000')".

So if you need to get the above records update the query with

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/events?$filter=(start/dateTime ge '2017-06-13T00:00:00.0000000' and end/dateTime le '2017-06-13T23:59:59.0000000')
```

Comment: Thanks Sudeep, you're right !
I will automatically add the time after my date and it'll be ok ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing part of the problem is that you are using the same value for both start time and end time. Note that this does not mean "any event on 13 June". Instead, it means, "any event whose start time is greater than or equal to `2017-06-13 00:00:00 UTC` and whose end time is less than or equal to `2017-06-13 00:00:00 UTC`". I can't explain why trying with only start date didn't work.

A similar query works for me in Graph Explorer: [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2016-06-01' and end/dateTime le '2016-06-02'&method=GET&version=v1.0](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/events?$filter=start/dateTime%20ge%20'2016-06-01'%20and%20end/dateTime%20le%20'2016-06-02'&method=GET&version=v1.0).

However, note that the thing you probably actually want is `calendarView`. `events` is a raw list of the events, `calendarView` takes recurrence into account.

Answer (score 0):

Normally for this type of operation you should use the [CalendarView](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_calendarview) rather than [Events](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_events). CalendarView will return the same results a user would normally see within Outlook.

Also, when looking for a single day you need to specify times, otherwise it will only return appointments that start and end at midnight. Alternatively you can use the following day without times (i.e. midnight to midnight):

'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2017-06-13&enddatetime=2017-06-14'